# How to make Flutter video player only start streaming after user tap play?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

I am trying Flutter `video_player` with `chewie`. I have tried both examples provided in:

- https://pub.dev/packages/video_player/example
- https://pub.dev/packages/chewie/example

Both work fine. Yet, even when the user does not tap on the screen, the video URL is immediately fetched and downloaded.

How can I postpone the video download until the user’s action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifiying the example from the chewie package and putting it inside of a `StatefulWidget`, we get:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';

class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExampleWidget> createState() => _ExampleWidgetState();
}

final VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
    Uri.parse('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4'));

class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {
  late final ChewieController chewieController;
  bool _initialized = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController, autoPlay: false, looping: true, autoInitialize: false);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    videoPlayerController.dispose();
    chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Chewie(controller: chewieController),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            if (!_initialized) {
              await videoPlayerController.initialize();
            }
            _initialized = true;
            await chewieController.play();
          },
          child: const Text("Play"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) => _build(context)))));

Widget _build(BuildContext context) {
  return const ExampleWidget();
}
```

By setting the `autoPlay` from the `ChewieController` to false, the video will not automatically play and by using the `chewieController.play()`, you can then start the video on pressing a button.

To also prevent the controller from preloading the video, only initialize the `videoPlayerController` in the callback method once instead of inside of the `initState` method.

This will load the video the first time the `Play` button is pressed (But remember that in this example clicking inside of the video itself would show the error symbol).
Instead you could also display some kind of loading Widget instead while the `initialized` bool is false and only show the Video Player otherwise. Or set the param `showControls`to false inside of the `ChewieController`.

Comment: The problem is not with auto play. The problem is with pre downloading.

Comment: uhm, i'm sorry, i don't know how i misread that. one minute, i'll adjust my answer.

Comment: updated my answer now to also include pre downloading

Comment: The key insight is in the `autoInitialize`. It solves the problem. Also your sample is much clear than former example from chewie repo. I felt awkward with those void functions initialisers with side effects on former example. I like that you prefer `final` fields and avoid `Nullable` where is possible.Thanks

Comment: BTW now that we delay initialisation. Is there any way of presenting a thumbnail from an Image?

Comment: No Problem. 
Just one more thing: the `autoInitialize` would only automatically call the `videoPlayerController.initialize`, but it is also false by default. I only included it for clarity. 

And you could also use the bool `videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized` instead of the separate `_initialized` bool inside of the state.

Comment: As for a custom thumbnail image, you could display a stack with an Image widget that covers everything depending on the initialized bool.